# $http.post for web api

Tags: angularjs, post, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I have controller action below in asp.net

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("ReportProblem")]
public IHttpActionResult ReportProblem(int BusinessID, int RoomID, int RoomFacilityID, int ComponentID, string[] BinImages, string ProblemDesc)
{
    return Ok("Thank you for reporting the issue.");
}
```

Now, I want to post using angularjs as below. But it is not working.

```
$http.post('/api/room/ReportProblem?BusinessID=1' +
'&RoomID=1'+
'&RoomFacilityID=1' +
'&ComponentID=1' +
'&BinImages=null' +
'&ProblemDesc=eee',
{
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
)
.success(function (response) {
    console.log(
});
```

Comment: "It is not working" is not specific enough. Bring up the F12 developer tools in your browser, click the Network tab, and watch the call that's being made (if any). What gets returned by the server?

Comment: Please be specific on which http status code you receive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var ReportProblemObject = {BusinessID: 1, RoomID: 1, RoomFacilityID: 1, ComponentID: 1, BinImages: null, ProblemDesc: 'eee'};

var payLoad = $httpParamSerializerJQLike(ReportProblemObject);
$http.post('/api/room/ReportProblem', payLoad, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have I more issue. I want to send in binImages base64 image as array of chars. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What's the issue??

Comment: send the array same as you are sending other parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

    app.controller("mycontroller", ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http)
            {    

                $http.post('js/data.json').success (function(data){
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(data.orders));
                    $scope.jsondata = data;
                });
```

Comment: Please stop adding advertisement links to all your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

```
$http.post('/api/room/ReportProblem', 
{ BusinessID: 1,RoomID : 1,RoomFacilityID : 1}).success(function (res) { response = res; });
```